# Why does the size of my hash (from a csv) read exactly half the value of the number of lines?

Tags: linux, perl, hash

I've written a simple perl script to calculate the number of value and/or keys in a hash, which was created from the content of a csv. The csv looks like this:

```
311552047969,THE UPSETTERS   RETURN OF THE SUPER APE VINYL LP 1978 ,http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/UPSETTERS-RETURN-SUPER-APE-VINYL-LP-1978-/311552047969,56.0                  
322016291276,Queen A Kind Of Magic NZ Orange Vinyl,http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Queen-Kind-Magic-NZ-Orange-Vinyl-/322016291276,165.0                                          
252288285264,Goldfrapp Black cherry vinyl record lp,http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Goldfrapp-Black-cherry-vinyl-record-lp-/252288285264,70.0                                    
331782523967,Reggae vinyl johny pram pram ,http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Reggae-vinyl-johny-pram-pram-/331782523967,73.0                                                       
391392294381,Various vinyl albums,http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Various-vinyl-albums-/391392294381,102.24
```

Here is my script to calculate the number of lines.

```
#!/bin/perl


open CSV2, "<csv2" or die;
@csv2=<CSV2>;
close CSV2;


%hash = @csv2;

@keys = keys %hash;
@values = values %hash;

$size = @values;
print "Hash size is $size";
```

The actual number of lines in the csv is 6374, but the output from my code is saying exactly half that- 3187.

I'm sure there is a simple explanation for this, but why doesn't the size of the hash (i.e. the number of values/keys), match the number of lines in my csv?

Comment: What did you think the hash would contain?

Comment: Why are you reaching for the hash -- what do you indend to do with it?  If it's just about the number of lines a list (an array) is what you want.   If there is more, please let us know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign a list to a hash, Perl assumes the list is a list of key, value pairs.  So you are populating a hash in which key

```
'311552047969,THE UPSETTERS   RETURN OF THE SUPER APE VINYL LP 1978 ,http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/UPSETTERS-RETURN-SUPER-APE-VINYL-LP-1978-/311552047969,56.0'
```

has value

```
'322016291276,Queen A Kind Of Magic NZ Orange Vinyl,http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Queen-Kind-Magic-NZ-Orange-Vinyl-/322016291276,165.0'
```

and so on.

Answer (score 6):

When you assign a list to a hash, the even-indexed elements of the list become keys, and the odd-indexed elements of the list become values. Therefore, there will be half as many keys in the hash as there are elements in the list and half the number of values in the hash as there are elements in the list if the number of elements in the list is even. Otherwise, there will `n/2 + 1` keys and `n` values in the hash where `n` is the number of elements in the list.

What you probably wanted to do was to insert elements in to the hash keyed by the ID in column 0 of your CSV.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV_XS;

my @fields = qw( title url price);
my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({ allow_whitespace => 1});
my %data;

while (my $row = $csv->getline(\*DATA)) {
    my ($key) = shift @$row;
    next unless defined($key) and length($key);
    for ( @$row ) {
        s/^\s+//;
        s/\s+\z//;
    }
    @{ $data{$key} }{ @fields } = @$row;
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%data;

__DATA__
311552047969,THE UPSETTERS   RETURN OF THE SUPER APE VINYL LP 1978 ,http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/UPSETTERS-RETURN-SUPER-APE-VINYL-LP-1978-/311552047969,56.0
322016291276,Queen A Kind Of Magic NZ Orange Vinyl,http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Queen-Kind-Magic-NZ-Orange-Vinyl-/322016291276,165.0
252288285264,Goldfrapp Black cherry vinyl record lp,http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Goldfrapp-Black-cherry-vinyl-record-lp-/252288285264,70.0
331782523967,Reggae vinyl johny pram pram ,http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Reggae-vinyl-johny-pram-pram-/331782523967,73.0
391392294381,Various vinyl albums,http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Various-vinyl-albums-/391392294381,102.24
```

#### Output

```
$ ./pppp.pl
$VAR1 = {
          '252288285264' => {
                              'url' => 'http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Goldfrapp-Black-cherry-vinyl-record-lp-/252288285264',
                              'title' => 'Goldfrapp Black cherry vinyl record lp',
                              'price' => '70.0'
                            },
          '322016291276' => {
                              'price' => '165.0',
                              'title' => 'Queen A Kind Of Magic NZ Orange Vinyl',
                              'url' => 'http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Queen-Kind-Magic-NZ-Orange-Vinyl-/322016291276'
                            },
          '311552047969' => {
                              'url' => 'http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/UPSETTERS-RETURN-SUPER-APE-VINYL-LP-1978-/311552047969',
                              'title' => 'THE UPSETTERS   RETURN OF THE SUPER APE VINYL LP 1978',
                              'price' => '56.0'
                            },
          '331782523967' => {
                              'url' => 'http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Reggae-vinyl-johny-pram-pram-/331782523967',
                              'price' => '73.0',
                              'title' => 'Reggae vinyl johny pram pram'
                            },
          '391392294381' => {
                              'url' => 'http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Various-vinyl-albums-/391392294381',
                              'title' => 'Various vinyl albums',
                              'price' => '102.24'
                            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

A hash is a list, with consecutive elements paired.  So when you assign a list to a hash, key-value pairs are formed of consecutive pairs of its elements.

```
my %hash = (1, 'one', 2, 'two');   # %hash is: (1 => 'one', 2 => 'two')
```

The number of key-value pairs is half of the length of the original list.  If the list had odd number of elements this can't really be done as intended and you get a warning -- if you have warnings on, which you should *always do*.

If you actually want to only count the lines, get the length of the list

```
my $num_lines = scalar @csv2;  # or:  my $num_lines = @csv2;
```

---

If you want to organize the content by the apparent ID (the first field),  you can do for example

```
use warnings;
use strict;

# read the file into @csv2 ...

my %csv = map { split /,/, $_, 2 } @csv2;
```

The [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) is limited to returning `2` elements, which thus will be the first field, and the rest of the line, forming the key-value pair. Note that the 'rest of the line' retains the commas, and probably need be processed further. Which points us to using a module in the first place.